# get all JSON entries over x amount of calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, pagination, loops

I'm accessing a json file which has 50 entries per page over x amount of pages.
I have the total number of entries, say 500 - which amounts to 10 pages.

I get the data from json file for page 1, pass the data to an array and then repeat the function but this time for page 2.

I have created the function and it loops perfectly incrementing and fetching each page, but it doesn't wait for the json data to be parsed and passed to the array before looping again.

Basically I want to wait until the data has been processed and then continue on.

My code so far is roughly this:

```
function getJsonData(metroID){
        currentPageNo = 0;
        totalPages = 'x';
        count = 0;

    function jsonLoop(){    
        meroAreaSearchString = 'http://jsonurl'+currentPageNo;

        $.getJSON(meroAreaSearchString,{},function( data ){ 
            if(totalPages == 'x'){
                var totalEntries = data.resultsPage.totalEntries;
                var perPage = data.resultsPage.perPage;
                totalPages = (totalEntries/perPage);
                log(totalEntries+', '+perPage+', '+totalPages);
                log(Math.round(totalPages));
            }
            $.each(data.resultsPage.results.event, function(i,item){
                var name = item.displayName;
                var type = item.type;
                var valueToPush = new Array();
                valueToPush[0] = name;
                valueToPush[1] = type;
                valueToPush[3] = count;
                locations.push(valueToPush);
                count++;    
            });
            });

            if(currentPageNo == totalPages){
                log(locations);
                alert('finished processing all results');
            }else{
                currentPageNo++;    
                jsonLoop();
            }
                currentPageNo++;    
                jsonLoop();
        }
 }
```

Comment: You're requesting the same data multiple times?  Why not just request it once?

Comment: just set `async` to false? this seems like a terrible way to get your data, though.

Comment: jbabey, how would you do it? As I said above I'm new enough to coding so would love to see a more efficient way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making the request syncronous?
Just put this piece of code at the top of your function getJsonData

```
$.ajaxSetup({async:false});
```

You can specify the async option to be false to get a synchronous Ajax request. This will stop your function until the callback set some data.

Comment: Just be sure to set it back to `async:true` for those AJAX calls that really should be asynchronous. One misstep with this and it can break quite a bit of user experience. :D

Answer (score 0):

The `$.getJSON()` function fires off an AJAX request, and calls it's callback function when the AJAX call resolves successfully, if that makes any sense.

Basically, that just means that given a call `$.getJSON(url,data,callback);`, jQuery will fire an AJAX request to `url` passing `data` along with it, and call `callback` when that call resolves. Clear cut straightforward.

The thing you're missing here is that an AJAX call is just that -- as its name implies, its **asynchronous**. This means that throughout the whole lifetime of the AJAX call, it lets the other logic in your application run instead of waiting for it to finish.

So something like this:

```
$.getJSON(url, data, callback);
alert('foo');
```

... will most probably result in an `alert()` call happening before your AJAX call completes. I hope that made sense.

To make sure that something happens *after* your AJAX call completes, you put that logic inside the callback. That's really what the callback is for.

```
$.getJSON(url, data, function (d) {

    something_you_want_done_after_ajax_call();

});
```

In the context of your problem, you just have to put all that conditional recalling of `jsonLoop()` into your callback. It's not very obvious right now because of your indenting, but it's currently outside your callback.